# How to remove "generated from" tag?

Tags: github, electron

I see this message below my repo name. Is there any way to remove it? I used template for my app for a quick start, but in current form my app doesn't look like this template, because everything changed so much. I don't see any reason why it's still there.

[image: message]

Comment: There is now an open Github feedback to provide this feature https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/15900 Add your feedback or upvote

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same problem and at the time for writing this answer, there is no option of removing this from Github. So removed this tag by deleting the repository from Github and recreating a new one with the same name.

⚠️ This operation will preserve only the information stored in git, not all other Github features, i.e. issues, PRs, ... If your repository has been used for a while, this might not be the right time to do this anymore.

Specific instructions:

1. Make sure you have **cloned your repository** and all your non-stale branches are saved locally.

   ```
   git fetch
   ```
2. Delete the original repository in the Github web UI.
3. Create a new repository with the same name.
4. Push the branches you want back to the remote.

   ```
   git push
   ```

Comment: sadly I had to delete my repo because github still don't allow us to remove this tag

Answer (score 0):

#### First solution:

- `git clone` Clone the repository you want to delete.
- Delete your current repo, then create a new one.
- `git push` new repo.

> Warning: This of course wouldn't keep any of the contribution history however.

#### Second solution:

- Delete the template repo.

This is what I have tried, it is effective, and it will not have any other impact on the current repo, but it requires you to delete the template repo.

> I have not tried canceling the template setting, so I am not sure if it will work